# How to use showErrors function to show a centralized error message and change input border color

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the showError function with jQuery validate to output a single error message at the bottom of my form. The functionality of this is working. However, I have two small modifications I am trying to figure out.

1. How can I get the borders to change to a different color for the inputs with the errors.

Edit - I figured out #1 above. I just need to figure out #2.

2. Right now, if I fill in one input and then click into another input or anywhere else on the page, the error message '#formErrors` from the showErrors function populates. I only want it to populate when the user tries to submit the form.

Any ideas?

```js
var send = false;

 $('#catalogRequestForm').validate({
  ignore: [],
  rules: {
   first_name: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
   },
   last_name: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
   },
   address1: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 5
   },
   city: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
   }
  },
  errorPlacement: function() {
            return false;
        },
   showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
   $('#formErrors').html('All required fields must be completed before you submit the form.');
   this.defaultShowErrors();
  },
  submitHandler: function() {
            submit();
        },
 });
```

```css
#formErrors {
 color: #b82222;
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1rem;
 margin: 10px auto;
}
input.error {
  border: 1px solid #b82222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" id="catalogRequestForm">
  <!-- Form Fields -->
  <input type="text" class="input2" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name *">
  <input type="text" class="input2 margRightN" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name *">
  <input type="text" class="input block" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company Name">
  <input type="text" class="input block" id="address1" name="address1" placeholder="Address 1 *">
  <input type="text" class="input block" id="address2" name="address2" placeholder="Address 2">
  <input type="text" class="input3" id="city" name="city" placeholder="City *">
  <select class="input3" id="state" name="state">
    <option value="">State *</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  </select>
  <div id="formErrors"></div>
  <input id="requestSubmit" class="button" type="submit" value="Request Catalog">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right now, if I fill in one input and then click into another input or anywhere else on the page, the error message '#formErrors` from the showErrors function populates. I only want it to populate when the user tries to submit the form.

[As per documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors) for `showErrors`, it's also fired on `focusout` and `keyup`.  If you only want that message to show up when you submit the form, then use the `invalidHandler` instead of `showErrors`.

Also, your `submitHandler` was missing the `form` argument so it would never be able to properly submit anything.  Corrected below.

```
  submitHandler: function(form) { 
      form.submit();  // default behavior
  },
```

HOWEVER, this is exactly the default, so it's not even needed and `submitHandler` can be removed entirely in this case.

```js
var send = false;

$('#catalogRequestForm').validate({
  ignore: [],
  rules: {
    first_name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    },
    last_name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    },
    address1: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5
    },
    city: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    }
  },
  errorPlacement: function() {
      return false;
  },
  invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    $('#formErrors').html('All required fields must be completed before you submit the form.');
  }
});
```

```css
#formErrors {
  color: #b82222;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

input.error {
  border: 1px solid #b82222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" id="catalogRequestForm">
  <!-- Form Fields -->
  <input type="text" class="input2" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name *">
  <input type="text" class="input2 margRightN" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name *">
  <input type="text" class="input block" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company Name">
  <input type="text" class="input block" id="address1" name="address1" placeholder="Address 1 *">
  <input type="text" class="input block" id="address2" name="address2" placeholder="Address 2">
  <input type="text" class="input3" id="city" name="city" placeholder="City *">
  <select class="input3" id="state" name="state">
    <option value="">State *</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  </select>
  <div id="formErrors"></div>
  <input id="requestSubmit" class="button" type="submit" value="Request Catalog">
</form>
```